# How to exclude delete field from inlineformset but still allow delete

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have an inlineformset that I render in my template so the rows are horizontal. Annoyingly, when I loop through the fields to generate the html, this automatically also renders a delete checkbox. I've seen that this is part of visible_fields
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20929#comment:4

How can I get rid of this? I want to be able to hide it for now and then use javascript to show the checkboxes with a button. This way I can enter a 'delete mode'. So I still want the user to be able to delete things, I just want the field to stop rendering in my table on page load.

```
<--form is here, management form etc -->
    {% for form in existing_formset.forms %}
        <--field headings generated here-->
        <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">
        <-- visible fields: apparently includes delete checkbox-->
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <--generate horizontal rows with fields-->
            <td>
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
            {{ field }}                 
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    <--more stuff-->
```

Comment: Why not hide the delete fields with javascript on page load?

Comment: Good shout I'll have a go now

Comment: Struggling to get this to work seeing as there isn't a simple id assigned to the template element

Comment: Are you using a js library? in jquery you can do `$('[name*="DELETE"]')`

Comment: I ended up just generating the form fields separately, I'll have a look at this though thanks @IainShelvington